# How to Repair MAC OS disk from Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, mac, boot-camp, hfs+, paragon

In boot-camp environment my MAC OS boot disk has been spoiled by [Paragon HFS+](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows/) for windows-10. MAC used to be so stable. Unfortunate that I ended up installing Paragon.

[Many people](https://www.reddit.com/r/hackintosh/comments/4m0b8v/repairing_a_hfs_disk_from_within_windows_10/) have been struggling with the issue.

> Is there any way I could repair MAC OS without re-installing the OS?

**EDIT:**
I have tried mac internet recovery, but as I do not have time machine can't recover.  Really do not want to reinstall MAC & loose all the applications & licenses installed. As I am able to login on same mac perfect using Windows 10. I am very much hopeful to find some work-around to restore the MAC OS.

Kindly help.

Comment: Those were all Hackintosh users - though the cause was the same. Never, repeat never, allow any Windows disk tool to touch a Boot Camp drive. Windows simply doesn't understand how it's fooled into thinking it's in charge.

Comment: I guess your choices are... try to boot to Recovery or Internet Recovery. If no joy, then you'll need something like DiskWarrior or Drive Genius, or even Paragon's HD Manager - which is fine from the Mac side.